# Prove that for $X=g(Z)$ and $Y=h(Z)$ it holds $Cov(X,Y) \geq 0$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $Z$ be a real valued random variable and $g,h;(R,B) \to (R,B)$ measurable functions, either both increasing or both decreasing. Assume that $X$ and $Y$ are square integrable. Prove that for $X=g(Z)$ and $Y=h(Z)$ it holds $Cov(X,Y) \geq 0$.

I would start with $$Cov(X,Y) = Cov(g(Z),h(Z)) = E(g(Z)h(Z)) - E(g(Z))E(h(Z))$$

then I tried to apply Cauchy Inequality and the fact that $E(X^2)\geq E(X)^2$, however this yields not the required result.
By trying to integrate that out 
$$E(g(Z))= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(Z)*f(z) dz      $$
$$E(h(Z))= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}h(Z)*f(z) dz         $$
$$E(g(Z)h(Z))= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(Z)h(Z)*f(z) dz         $$
where I am also stuck.

I would appreciate any HINT, please only a hint since I would like to solve it on my own. Thanks!

Comment: Hint: Integrate on $\mathbb R^2$ the pointwise inequality, valid for every $(z,w)$, $$(g(z)-g(w))(h(z)-h(w))f(z)f(w)\geqslant0$$

Comment: Ok thanks! Some questions: 1. If i integrate that I get $E(((g(Z)-g(w))(h(Z)-h(W)))$ or? 2. How to come up with this inequality?

Comment: The pointwise inequality follows from the monotonicity of $g$. Integrating it yields $E((g(Z)g(W))(h(Z)-h(W)))\geqslant0$ where $W$ stands for an independent copy of $Z$, and now *one is supposed to develop the LHS and to identify each of the four expectations*...

Comment: @Did Thanks I gonna work it out!!

Comment: @Did But why E[g(Z)*g(W)...]?

Comment: Typo: $E((g(Z)-g(W))(h(Z)-h(W)))\geqslant0$. (Sorry but wasn't this *obvious*?)

Comment: @Did yeah just wanted be sure haha. THANKS a lot I got it now :)